# Barplot of two columns based on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was given a task where I'm supposed to plot a element based on another column element.

For further information here's the code:

```
# TODO: Plot the Male employee first name on 'Y' axis while Male salary is on 'X' axis
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = pd.read_excel("C:\\users\\HP\\Documents\\Datascience task\\Employee.xlsx")

print(data.head(5))
```

Output:

```
    First Name  Last Name   Gender           Age    Experience (Years)  Salary
0   Arnold  Carter           Male             21                10    8344
1   Arthur  Farrell          Male             20                 7    6437
2   Richard Perry            Male             28                 3    8338
3   Ellia   Thomas           Female           26                 4    8870
4   Jacob   Kelly            Male             21                 4    548
```

How to plot the 'First Name' column vs the 'Salary' column of the first 5 rows of where the 'Gender' is Male.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First generate the male rows separately and extract first name and salary for plotting.

The below code identifies first five male employees and converts their first name and salary as x and y lists.

```
x = list(df[df['Gender'] == "Male"][:5]['Fname'])
y = list(df[df['Gender'] == "Male"][:5]['Salary'])
print(x)
print(y)
```

**Output:**

```
['Arnold', 'Arthur', 'Richard', 'Jacob']
[8344, 6437, 8338, 548]
```

Note that there're only 4 male available in the df.

Then we can plot any chart as we require;

```
plt.bar(x, y, color = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']);
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Its works just like how I wanted thanks. But is 'list()' necessary?

Answer (score 1):

`seaborn` can help as well

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.plotly as plt

sns.barplot( x=df[(df['Gender'] == "Male")]['First Name'][:5] , y = df[(df['Gender'] == "Male")]['Salary'][:5] )

plt.xlabel('First Names')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.title('Barplot of Male Employees')
plt.show()
```